# Deriving gravitational acceleration from the formula for the force of gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, earth

I'm trying to derive this $g = 9.8 m/s^2$ from this 
$$F = G\frac{m_E\cdot m_2}{(r)^2}$$

So I did:

$$g = G \frac{(5.972\cdot 10^{24}kg)}{(6.371km)^2} \Leftrightarrow \\
g = 6.67\cdot10^{-11}Nm^2/kg^2\cdot 0.147\cdot10^{24}kg/km^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
g = 0.98\cdot10^{13}\frac{Nm^2}{kg\cdot km^2} \\ \Leftrightarrow \\
g = 0.98\cdot 10^{13}\frac{m^3/s^2}{10^3m^2} \Leftrightarrow \\g = 0.98\cdot10^{10}m/s^2$$

What went wrong?

Comment: Please be aware that check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two formulas are in general valid:

1. $$F_g=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$$
2. $$F_g=mg$$
   So we can combine them into:
   $$F_g=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\iff mg=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\iff g=G\frac{M}{r^2}$$
   And then we just calculate:
   $$g=G\frac{M}{r^2}=6.67\cdot 10^{-11}\frac{m^3}{kg\cdot s^2}\frac{5.972\cdot 10^{24}kg}{6371000^2m^2}=9.8136\frac{m}{s^2}\approx 9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$$

where

1. $G$ is the gravitational constant, $G = 6.67\cdot 10^{-11}\frac{m^3}{kg\cdot s^2}$
2. $M$ is the mass of Earth, $M = 5.972\cdot 10^{24}kg$
3. $r$ is the radius of the Earth, $r=6371km=6371000m$
4. $g$ is final result - gravitational acceleration, $g=9.81\frac{m}{s^2}$

The actual value is $g = 9.81\frac{m}{s^2}$, so we got right.

Comment: I have a question: Is gravity's acceleration a sort of centripetal acceleration?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire In the free fall not. You are just falling downwards. But you can take two stars (binary star). They are orbiting around each other with a help of gravity. They are accelerating in both magnitude and direction, so also centripetal. So, yes - gravity can make centripetal acceleration.